# Factoring Perfect Square Trinomials

Tags: factoring

How would you factor perfect square trinomials? I have a perfect square trinomial `4x^2 - 20x + 25 = 0`, and the answer given to me on the answer key is `(2x - 5)^2`. How do I get to this answer?

Comment: you generally do it by [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice 
$$X^2\pm 2XY+Y^2=(X\pm Y)^2.$$

Yours is the $(X,Y)=(2x,5)$ case.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now! Once I get 15 reputation points, I will vote your answer up if I remember to do so.

Comment: You are welcome!